# How do I repeat section and subsection numbers in same document?

Tags: sectioning

I am writting a Question paper in latex. I customize section and subsection and use them as A(section) and A-1(subsection) to specify questions and subquestions. Now I want same section and subsection numbering in same document. See, Again I want to write 'A' in OBJECTIVE TYPE QUESTIONS. I tried but did not get answer. Help me!

![example image][1]

Comment: The section and subsection numbers are stored in the section or subsection counters, in order to print them, use `\thesection` and `\thesubsection`, assuming `\arabic` output formatting, so `A\thesection` or `A-\thesubsection` should do

Comment: Thanks, for your response. It's done. The problem is, I want again 'A' section and subsection 'A-1'. Just like in image. How I can do this.

Comment: \renewcomand{\thesection}{\Alph{section} and \renewcommand{\thesubsection){\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}

Comment: if you want to restart the section numbering, `\setcounter{\section}{0}` just before you issue the `\section` command where you want "A" to be used again.  (you have already defined the format, so that should persist.)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks all,  Thanks ,  barbara beeton, your solution can solve my problem. but it is gving error '! Missing \endcsname inserted'. I defined \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}   in the preample. And as you said I used \setcounter{\section}{0} but it is not working.

Comment: Thanks, Henri Menke for pointing out my mistake. I will take care.

Comment: `\setcounter{section}{0}`  (no backslash) blame @barbarabeeton :-)

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman -- david carlisle caught my typo -- shouldn't be a backslash on the counter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of my problem is written below:

```js
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}   %% write in preamble
\setcounter{section}{0}                    %% write in preamble
%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBLE END %%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{document}
\section{}                       
\section{}
\section{} 
\section{}              %% section no. 'D' here
\usecounter{section} %% For section no.'A' in same document.Problem solved
\section{Objective}
some text here
\end{document}
```

Comment: what i meant in my answer was that `\setcounter{section}{0}` should be placed immediatedly before `\section{Objective}`, *not* in the preamble, which is redundant, but doesn't do any harm.  presence of minimum example code showing the context would have enabled easy modification of that example to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

since you wish to reuse exactly the same section and subsection numbers, all you need to do is restart the section counter at the appropriate point.  you have already defined the format of the counters, so that should persist.

to restart the counter, place this command just before you want "A" to be used again:

```
\setcounter{section}(0)
```

(note that there should *not* be a backslash in the name of the counter.  my comment was incorrect on that point, which caused an error message when you tried it.)

Comment: Thanks, all. My mistake was I exactly wrote that @ barbara beeton  written over here. Not worked! After that I remove \(bakslash) inside{} (curly brace) and wrote \setcounter{section}(0). But this is not a complete command. It did not solve my problem. I am posting a solution which solved my problem.